# Knockout databind on two variable

Tags: knockout.js

Is it possible to databind the `enable` property to two variables in KO?

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="enable: (prop1 || prop2), click: $root.rootProp />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely can enable a checkbox based on two properties.

If this is your HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="enable: prop1() || prop2()" />
```

And this is your view model:

```
var viewModel = {
        prop1 : ko.observable(false),
        prop2 : ko.observable(true)
    };

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qja0fh13/), and play around setting `prop1` and `prop2` to `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`ko.computed`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)

```
this.enabled = ko.computed(function () {
    // get observable value
    return this.prop1() || this.prop2();
}, this);

data-bind="enable: enabled,
```

Comment: If OP is using observables (which is suggested based on `prop1 || prop2` not working in the view code), then that computed observable [will always evaluate to true](http://jsfiddle.net/qja0fh13/1/). OP needs to add parenthesis in their view code similarly to how parenthesis are needed here in the computed.